# How to pipe md5 hash result in shell

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell-script, hashsum

I am looking for a simple way to pipe the result of `md5sum` into another command. Something like this:

```
$echo -n 'test' | md5sum | ...
```

My problem is that `md5sum` outputs not only the hash of the string, but also an hypen, which indicates that the input came from stdin. I checked the man file and I didn't find any flags to control output.

Comment: Note: be careful not to use `echo -n` when the text data is unknown. Use `printf '%s' "$DATA"` instead. Unlike `echo -n "$DATA"`, it will work when `DATA="-n"` (among other examples).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the command [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut); it allows you to cut a certain character/byte range from every input line. Since the MD5 hash has fixed length (32 characters), you can use the option `-c 1-32` to keep only the first 32 characters from the input line:

```
echo -n test | md5sum | cut -c 1-32
```

Alternatively, you can tell `cut` to split the line at the every space and output only the first field: (note the quotes around the space character)

```
echo -n test | md5sum | cut -d " " -f 1
```

See the [cut manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) for more options.

Comment: I thought about that also! I chose `-d`+`-f` so that `md5sum` can be replaced with `sha1sum` or whatever later.

Comment: `awk` works too:

    `echo -n test | md5sum | awk -F" " '{print $1}'`  or `awk -F" " '{print $1}' <(echo -n test | md5sum)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. @laebshade Actually, you have to use printf otherwise it will output a new line character at the end ;)

Comment: @laebshade: the `-F" "` option to `awk` is very strange to see, given that it is the default for `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

You can `cut` it:

```
echo -n 'test' | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Here, `-d' '` chooses space as delimiter, and `-f1` asks for the first field (before a delimiter).

Answer (score 2):

Using *awk* works fine too :

```
echo -n 'test' | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

Another way is making a substring. Because you know md5 hash is a string with 32 characters, you could use :

```
HASH=$(echo -n 'test' | md5sum -) && echo ${HASH:0:32}
```

It's just string manipulations, so you got the choice !